# .htaccess with Ajax datatables

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a php project where i use datatables with ajax, all was working perfectly until i added .htaccess file to remove .php from links and to rename some folder as follows

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 # pass-through if another rewrite rule has been applied already
 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^share/(.*?)(\.php)?$ /reports/$1 [R=307,NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=307,NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/share/$1.php -f
 RewriteRule ^reports/(.*)$ share/$1.php [L,NC]

 RewriteRule ^reports/(.*)$ share/$1 [L,NC]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

the reason i'm using redirect_status 200 cuz i don't want to add END as my apache version is 2.2 and i don't want to upgrade it 
,any ideas what have gone wrong ?

Edit: print the $_REQUEST in the php that ajax calls

```
   Array
 (
    [draw] => 1
[columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 0
[columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 1
[columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 2
[columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 3
[columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 4
[columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 5
[columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 6
[columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 7
[columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 8
[columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D] => 9
[columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D] => 
[columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D] => true
[columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D] => true
[columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D] => false
[order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D] => 0
[order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D] => asc
[start] => 0
[length] => 10
[search%5Bvalue%5D] => 
[search%5Bregex%5D] => false
[_] => 1493734100074
  )
```

so the php file can't read proper values of $_REQUEST which screws things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you have removed .php from the extension and you might be using a code like below in your codebase -

```
       $.ajax({ url: '/your/site',
     data: {action: 'test.php'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(abc) {
                  alert(xyz);
              }
       });
```

Try removing the .php from the ajax call, here is how your code should look like

```
  $.ajax({ url: '/your/site',
 data: {action: 'test'},
 type: 'post',
 success: function(abc) {
              alert(xyz);
          }
   });
```

this is a possible solution to your problem, let me know if it works.

Comment: just found that i was using type get which messes with the request